# Algorithm to find string which is longest and contains lowest possible numbers?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I have to find string out of these which is longest and contains the lowest possible numbers.

1. 10,20
2. 10,20,30
3. 10,30,40
4. 30,40,50

Ans 10,20,30

I am trying to think of algorithm which can be used to find such record.

```
Record will not contain duplicate number for example e.g 10,10,20 won't be case.
```

Comment: When you say "which is longest", do you mean the string with the most numbers or the string with the most characters?

Comment: @PeterConstable string with most numbers

Comment: @גלעדברקן Both are important. Find longest and containing lowest possible numbers.

1,1000 is answer in this case

Comment: Start by writing a comparison function that compares two sequences, and returns a value indicating which sequence is better. For example, which is better: `1, 100` or `10, 20, 30`?

Comment: Most numbers, or most unique numbers? (E.g., 1,1,1,1,1,2 vs 1,50?)

Comment: @PeterConstable there won't be any duplicate in string. Out of 1,2 or 1,50. Answer would be 1,2

Comment: And how do you define "lowest possible numbers"? (e.g., 1,50 vs.20,30?)

Comment: @PeterConstable 1,50. It contains 1 as lowest so its lowest possible number in it.

Comment: @user3386109 1, 100

Comment: After you've written the comparison function, the problem is the same as finding the minimum in an array of numbers.

Comment: @Heisenberg You don't want to simply compare the minimums. You compare the first elements and if one is lower then that's the answer. If they're equal then compare the second elements. If those are equal then compare the third elements and so on. It's a [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Based on clarification of requirements:

- split strings by delimiters and convert to lists of (unique) numbers
- determine the max # of elements, M, in any list
- get the set of lists with M elements
- for each list, find the min element
- pick the list with the lowest min

Comment: If I think correctly. If I find that way I would have two records left viz 10,20,30 10,30,40 or may be I haven't understood the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a general solution for problems where you need to find a string out of a collection of strings.

In case your data can be sorted then use a `PriorityQueue`.

From the docs:

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap. The elements of
> the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or
> by a Comparator

```
    PriorityQueue<String> a = new PriorityQueue<>((o1, o2) -> {
        int compare = Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
        if(compare != 0){
            return compare;
        }
        
        int result = compare numbers...

        return result;
    });

    a.add("10,20");
    a.add("10,20,30");
    a.add("10,30,40");
    a.add("30,40,50");

    System.out.println(a.remove()); // 10,20,30
```

In case it's not, use any List and do the filtering one by one.